# Kubernetes CPU/Memory Resource Allocation on Pod not correct

Tags: kubernetes, memory, cpu, kubernetes-pod

I have a deployment template which has below resources settings:

```
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  8Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  2Gi
```

I believe the Kubernetes will allocate my pod with CPU between 500m ~ 2 core, and memory between 2Gi ~ 8Gi.

However, when I ssh into the pod, when I run below command to get the CPU/Memory, seems the resource allocation is not correct:

```
[root@xxx /]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       15950120 kB
MemFree:         6629072 kB
MemAvailable:   12728888 kB
```

15950120 kB is around 15.9 Gi.

```
grep 'cpu cores' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq
cpu cores   : 2
```

The CPU on the pod is 2 core.

So my question is why I set the limit for the memory is 8Gi, but I got 16Gi in total?

Also for the CPU, I just request 500m core but why it shows 2cores?

Comment: what kubernetes installation/cloud you use?

Comment: kube v1.18, AWS EKS, I have 3 on-demand node, each node is m5.xlarge

Answer (score 0):

You know, there is an explanation from the official [Managing Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) kubernetes documentation, why there are 2 cores instead of 500m, but it is hard to understand how happend 16Gi instead of 8Gi..

SO basically, documentation sais,

> **If the node where a `Pod` is running has enough of a resource available,
> it's POSSIBLE (and ALLOWED)** **for a container TO USE MORE RESOURCES than
> its request for that resource specifies. However, a container is not
> allowed to use more than its resource limit.**
>
> For example, if you set a memory request of 256 MiB for a container,
> and that container is in a Pod scheduled to a Node with 8GiB of memory
> and no other Pods, then the container can try to use more RAM.

Comment: if ill found anything more useful  - Ill update the answer

Comment: Any luck? I'm seeing similar for memory. Expecting a 1.5GB limit but MemTotal is 11GB.

Comment: I think it's reporting the total memory available to the entirety of (in my case) docker desktop. Rather than the container's limit, which isn't particularly helpful.